# In-line Backtick Escapes Not Formatting Text as Code

Tags: support, markdown, inline-code, backtick

I'm trying to insert backtick escapes to highlight (with a gray background) in-line text as ˋcodeˋ, but the text surrounded by the backticks appears as regular text (as in ˋthis textˋ). Not sure if I'm typing the correct key on the keyboard; I'm using the key under the <kbd>Esc</kbd> key and to the left of the <kbd>1</kbd> key.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

After reading @Glorfindel's answer, I checked the settings of the Clipboard Master program I have installed and running on my PC. From the task bar, I right-clicked on the Clipboard Master icon > Settings > Settings > Keyboard > Global hotkeys > and unchecked the "ˋ" Key combination who's function is to "Show diacritics and umlaute". This fixed the issue and now the keyboard backtick generated is recognized by the markdown engine, allowing me to `format in-line text as code`. Thanks!

Answer (score 7):

You're using a character which [identifies](http://www.babelstone.co.uk/Unicode/whatisit.html) as

```
U+02CB : MODIFIER LETTER GRAVE ACCENT
```

while the 'correct' one, `` ` `` is

```
U+0060 : GRAVE ACCENT
```

It reminds me of the (annoying) Windows function which doesn't display an accent directly upon typing, but waits for another letter to be pressed, so e.g. <kbd>`</kbd> + <kbd>e</kbd> becomes `è`. Maybe there's some strange setting in your OS, or a keyboard helper tool, which is the cause for this?

Comment: Your answer and suggestion led me to identify the issue and resolution, which I posted. Thank you!

Comment: This "annoying" feature is called a [dead key](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dead_key) and is present (and necessary!) in most systems when the right keyboard layout is active.

Comment: Or wrong keyboard layout, depending on your point of view.

Comment: @isanae thanks, I didn't know the term. I know it has its uses for languages with a lot of diacritics (French, German, Polish) but it's not needed for English and highly counterproductive for software developers, so it would be better to make this an *optional* feature.

Comment: @Glorfindel It _is_ optional. You're probably using some sort of "international English" layout instead of US English. Check your settings.

Comment: Yeah, I've already switched it off :)

Answer (score 3):

I plugged your backtick into the Clojure REPL on my phone:

```
(int \ˋ)
=> 715
```

You're using some kind of fancy backtick that the markdown engine doesn't recognize. Normal backticks have a code of 96.